# Using a bower angular dependency in an es6 module

Tags: angularjs, webpack, components, bower

I have a legacy bower package that is defined like this:

`angular.module('legacy', [...]);`

In my new application, I have a series of components that I need to look  like this:

```
angular.module('newstuff', ['legacy'])
  .component('comp1', comp1)
  .component('comp2', comp2)
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to include the bower dependency in a way that it's accessible. I'm using modules to access dependencies in `newstuff`, but `legacy` requires a few libraries to be global. No matter what I seem to try, `legacy` is undefined when `newstuff` is declared, causing a module-doesn't-exist exception.

How can I use a bower angular dependency in a new project with module loading?